# Curl not giving any response back

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl get the response back from a file on different server..

Curl code:

```
$url="http://example.com/trck.php?adrs=yy";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

trck.php Code:

```
$url=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['adrs']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM product where site = '$url'";
$res=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die( mysqli_error() );
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0 || $row['status']==0)
{
return no;

}
else
{
return yes;
}
```

but there is no response form it.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: trck.php does not echo a text.

Comment: also tried echo but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['adrs']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM product where site = '$url'";
$res=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die( mysqli_error() );
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0 || $row['status']==0)
{
echo 'no';
}
else
{
echo 'yes';
}
```

also:

```
$url="http://example.com/trck.php?adrs=yy";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

you have to echo the returned transfer from curl.

Comment: How is that unexpected ? U have to change the host from `example` to where ever the file trck.php is hosted